# Replace form.change from react-final-form in react-admin v4

Tags: react-admin

I have this component made for react-admin v3 that allows me to generate an id code. Now I'm upgrading to version 4 of react-admin and I don't know how to replace the part of the code where I do.

`form.change("referredCode", code);`

Here is the complete code of the component.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { TextInput, useDataProvider, LoadingIndicator } from "react-admin";
import { useForm } from "react-final-form";
import { randomIdGenerator } from "../../helpers/randomIdGenerator";

export default function UserReferredCode({ record }) {
  const { referredCode } = record;
  const [code, setCode] = useState("");
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const dataProvider = useDataProvider();
  const form = useForm();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!referredCode) {
      // Generar id aleatorio
      setIsLoading(true);
      setCode(randomIdGenerator(6));
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (code) {
      dataProvider
        .getList("users", {
          pagination: { page: 1, perPage: 1 },
          filter: { referredCode: code },
        })
        .then(({ data }) => {
          if (data.length > 0) {
            setCode(randomIdGenerator(6));
          } else {
            setIsLoading(false);
          }
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          console.log(e);
        });
    }

    form.change("referredCode", code);
  }, [code]);

  return (
    <>
      {isLoading ? (
        <LoadingIndicator />
      ) : (
        <TextInput
          disabled
          source="referredCode"
          name="referredCode"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Code"
          initialValue={referredCode || code}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have a `Form` component wrapping all of this.

Check the `Form` documentation https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/4.0/Form.html

then you you can access it from `useFormContext()` (from react-hook-form).

the form has action **setValue** that accepts name and value

https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue